# Does a Kenyan citizen holding a Schengen visa need a transit visa as well if having a layover in Zurich?

Tags: schengen, transit-visas, switzerland

I will be travelling with a family member from Dublin, Ireland to Nice, France at the end of next month in November. She is a Kenyan citizen but already has a Schengen visa that lasts until March 2019 so we figured that we don't need any more paperwork.

I see when trying to locate tickets that some offer a layover in Zurich. We are a bit worried if she'd need a transit visa because some countries require one. She tells me that Switzerland is not in the Schengen area and thus, she might need a visa when transiting. Is this true or not? Thanks

Comment: Switzerland joined the Schengen area somewhat late in the game, but it did indeed join.

Answer (score 4):

Your companion is mistaken - Switzerland *is* in the Schengen zone ([Source](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/schengen-visa-countries-list/))

She should be fine with her visa, no transit visa required.

Comment: Of course if the visa is only single entry, it would be used up.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Of course, since the final destination is in France, it wouldn't matter that a single entry visa would be used up in Switzerland, since there would be no further entries.

Comment: Yes, but a pre-existing visa would have (theoretically) been for a specific trip, not necessarily this one.